# JHD204A - 20x4 dispay

Tags: pi-2, display

I got a jhd 20x4 digital display last week and tried to setup with my Raspberry pi. After performing the setup the Backlight dispay comes up but when I send some message that is not getting reflected.

1. Is it because the display has gone bad.

I had followed the wiring suggested by Matt

http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/08/20x4-lcd-module-control-using-python/

I have also asked Matt on the same. Any help in tweaking this will save my day.

Comment: It might be really helpful if you attached some details of exactly how you have attached the display ... and exactly what software you used.  The backlight is no more than power to an LED so it being lit isn't (unfortunately) much of a clue.  Experience says that a wrong wiring is most likely going to be the culprit.

Comment: have you adjusted the contrast - most displays have a contrast pot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this working. This was a connection issue which I identified by removing the header pins from the 16 pin slot and re soldered with the new set of pin. It works well now. Thanks for the answers Kolban and Steve